# $_POST data being truncated after double quote

Tags: php, post, simplexml

We have a server running PHP 5.3 with magic quotes ON:

magic_quotes_gpc On On 
magic_quotes_runtime Off Off

Whenever we receive a POST (CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded) that contains XML that's un-sanitized (has quotes,&,<,> in the element payload), SimpleXML cannot parse it.

When I look at the raw $_POST dump, the XML is truncated from the 1st illegal character forward. Never seen this before.

Then, I added htmlspecialchars and all is happy and the XML is able to be parsed by SimpleXML.

```
$payload = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($postXMLPayload)));
```

This suggests that the full, albeit illegal XML is indeed in the $_POST array but when I try to see it, it's truncated.

I am emailing the value in $_POST and also databasing it and in both cases
the value in $_POST is truncated.

Here is how I am getting the $_POST value

```
if(isset($_POST)){

foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){

    if(preg_match('/^\<\?xml/',trim($v))){

        $postXMLPayload = $v;
        break;
    }

}
```

}

Can someone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: the post is most likely not being truncated. if you are simply echo'ing it out, it is most likely being treated as an open html tag. view the source when echo'ing it out and you would most likely see the entire xml.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. I am actually saving the $_POST value in a variable and emailing and databasing the value that way.